# Swap/Change div content using links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple projects with content (overview, details). *I am very new to JQuery*

1. How can I replace the content in the same location instead of below?
2. How do I keep the content on other projects from disappearing?

HTML:

```
<div id="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <!-- Start project 1-->
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h3>First Project Title</h3>
    <div class="project-desc">
      <div class="div1">
        <p>First project overview here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div2" style="opacity:0">
        <p>More detailed description here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-nav">
      <a href="#project" data-id="1">Overview</a>
      <a href="#project" data-id="2">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of project 1 -->

  <!-- Start project 2 -->
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h3>Second Project Title</h3>
    <div class="project-desc">
      <div class="div3">
        <p>Second project overview here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div4" style="opacity:0">
        <p>More detailed description here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-nav">
      <a href="#project" data-id="3">Overview</a>
      <a href="#project" data-id="4">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of project 2 -->
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $(".project-nav a").click(function() {
    var target = '.div' + $(this).attr("data-id");
    $(".project-desc >div").css("opacity", "0");
    $(target).css("opacity", "1");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

All together: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7xfxqnp/1/)

Comment: _"How can I replace the content in the same location instead of below?"_ Don't change the opacity, change the display

Comment: So what you mean with your first question is that "More detailed description here" should be replaced with "First project overview here" instead of showing under the other string? What you mean with your second question is that string under the second project disappeared when your press the first project?

Comment: @Steven : Exactly!

Comment: @j08691 I tried the .show() .hide() but they didn't work. Is there another I should be using?

Comment: I rewrote things a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/zowoxpgc/ (I mostly tried to remove unnecessary `<div>`s)

Comment: @ChrisG : Can you post this under "Answer your Question"? This is it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".project").each(function() {
        let $project = $(this);
        $project.find("nav a").click(function() {
            $project.find(".project-info > p").hide();
            $project.find("." + $(this).attr("href")).show();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.project {
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.project-image {
    display: block
}

.details {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projects">
    <h2>Projects</h2>
    <!-- Start project 1 -->
    <div class="project">
        <img class="project-image" src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
        <div class="project-info">
            <h3>First Project Title</h3>
            <p class="overview">First project overview here</p>
            <p class="details">More detailed description here</p>
            <nav>
                <a href="overview">Overview</a>
                <a href="details">Details</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of project 1 -->

    <!-- Start project 2 -->
    <div class="project">
        <img class="project-image" src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
        <div class="project-info">
            <h3>Second Project Title</h3>
            <p class="overview">Second project overview here</p>
            <p class="details">More detailed description here</p>
            <nav>
                <a href="overview">Overview</a>
                <a href="details">Details</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of project 2 -->
</div>
```

I focused on slimming down the HTML and making the nav functionality flexible so you can arbitrarily add projects and nav links without worrying about existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

as @j08691 said, simply replace `opacity:0` with `display: none` and `opacity: 1;` with `display: block;` see modified [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a54e6twt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have also solved it but I think It can be easier done. Then what I did. But why go easy if you can do it on a hard way without CSS.

I have deleted some div in the HTML.

What I did is good exercise for JQuery

```js
var showTheRightStuffAtTheRightPlace = function(){
  var $selector = $(this);
  var whatProject = $selector.attr("data-id");
  var whatDoINeedToShow = $selector.html();
  var String;
  switch(whatDoINeedToShow){
    case 'Overview':
      String = '<p>First project overview here</p>'
    break;
    case 'Details':
      String = '<p>More detailed description here</p>';
    break;
  }
  $('.' + whatProject).html(String);
};


var init = function () {
 $(".project-nav").on('click','a',showTheRightStuffAtTheRightPlace);
};
$(document).ready(init());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <!-- Start project 1-->
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h3>First Project Title</h3>
    <div class="project-desc project1">
    </div>
    <div class="project-nav">
      <a href="#project" data-id="project1">Overview</a>
      <a href="#project" data-id="project1">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of project 1 -->

  <!-- Start project 2 -->
  <div class="project-image">
    <img src="http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SmallTriambicIcosahedron.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="project-info">
    <h3>Second Project Title</h3>
    <div class="project-desc project2">
     
    </div>
    <div class="project-nav">
      <a href="#project" data-id="project2">Overview</a>
      <a href="#project" data-id="project2">Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of project 2 -->
</div>
```